# Can't get flyout dynamic menus to work for top navigation

Tags: navigation

I can't get the fly out menus to work for top navigation in SharePoint 2010.
I have changed both the MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels and the StaticDisplayLevels to 2 using Sharepoint Designer but still no luck.

This was quite easy with WSS v3.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've removed the reference to the specific 'Foundation' product as I believe this question applies to any edition of SP2010. If for some reason you feel this is wrong please rollback the edit.

Comment: Thanks Alex...
Hope i get a solution to this

Answer (score 1):

I answered another question last month that is probably related:

[How can we hide the root menu item in navigation?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5773/how-can-we-hide-the-root-menu-item-in-navigation/5774#5774)

Comment: Anders thans for the reply.
But i don't understand what really needs to be done.Do you mean we have to remove the delegate control for it to work?

Comment: Either that or add a delegate control with **lower** sequence. If you just need to try different combos of menu and data source properties, you could temporarily edit your master page using SharePoint designer removing delegates and ensuring your code runs. Remember though that this will leave your master page unghosted, so this should only be a temporary solution for getting the navigation concept right